# Magento 2.3.3 Save Config not works

Tags: magento2

I have an issue on magento 2 site. The button "Save Config" not work, I click on in but nothing.

My configuration: magento2.3.3 on VPS with Plesk and php 7.3.

How can solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your screenshot

Comment: Hi Vishal, look this: https://video.drift.com/v/aby3aoVnwt6/

Comment: is check-in console any error display?

Comment: Yes, but there aren't error

Comment: so need to check button inspect element has added disable property true need to remove property and after save working or not .

Comment: Hi, this problem is caused by the Chrome Browser, I have used firefox now and works. but I can't explain why with chrome sometimes it doesn't save the configuration and with co firefox instead it works well.

Comment: please check in private mode in the chrome browser.